# How to make my app not visible in market only for android 4.03 and 4.04 versions?

Tags: android, sdk, version

I need to make my app unvisible for and 4.03 and 4.04 versions, but I want it to be visible for lower and higher versions (lets say from 2.1 to 4.0 and from 4.1 JellyBean ->)

I know i could specify android maxsdkVersion to  14 but that would exclude JellyBean which I want to be included.
So how to exclude just 4.03 and 4.04 versions?

Comment: I am just wondering why you want this?

Comment: Because it seems that there's an OpenGL error that happens only on android 4.04 version. But app works good on any other versions above 2.1 included)

Comment: The only way I'd know to do this would be to create two packages, one for Android <4.0.3 and one for Android >4.0.4. However, I think the better approach would be to have your app recognize when it's running on problematic Android versions, and explain it to the user. If you don't do that, you're running the risk of upsetting existing users when they upgrade to 4.0.3...

Comment: I wouldn't exclude those versions even if there are bugs. You have no guarantee that really all devices running 4.0.4 are broken. From your other question `MaliEGL` for example is only on specific devices with a [Mali GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali_%28GPU%29). If you find no way to fix it and don't want angry customers, blacklist devices that don't work or put a warning in your app description.

Comment: hmm thanks for advices, I think I'll do exactly as You say.